# Sitecore 7.2 sometimes publishes to the wrong target

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I have two publishing targets: preview & live.  Occasionally, when I publish to preview, the content also publishes to live.  I did find a publishing agent set to publish to live every 5 minutes and disabled that in all of the environments.  If anyone has any ideas how I might debug this, or what the problem might be, please post.  I've inherited this website in mid-configuration, and the backend is a little sloppy right now.

Comment: Why not use the master DB as a source for the preview in the first place?

Comment: Exactly.  That's what we wound up doing.  As I mentioned, I inherited this and there was some confusion between what the owner wanted and what the previous vendor was configuring.  It was a lot of trouble for nothing, really.  Also, the real issue was the the site was configured to publish automatically to live every 10 minutes.